# Mercurial .hgignore negative lookbehind regex

Tags: regex, mercurial, hgignore

I'm trying to ignore everything but file "test.ext" in directory "data" & all of it's subdirectories.
however when i put in hgignore:

```
syntax: regexp
^data\/.*(?<!\/test\.ext)$
```

It only ignores

```
data\test.ext
```

And does not ignore:

```
data\images\test.ext
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless new subdirectories pop up often, you're much better off just ignoring `data` and then `hg add`ing the `test.ext` files you want tracked.   Adding a file 100% overrides ignore, and running `find data -name test.ext | xargs hg add` once in a blue moon is better than a tortured regex.

Answer (score 1):

From [the hg docs](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/.hgignore):
"There is no straightforward way to ignore all but a set of files. Attempting to use an inverted regex match will fail when combined with other patterns. This is an intentional limitation, as alternate formats were all considered far too likely to confuse users to be worth the additional flexibility."